# Problems with basic mktime() in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, mktime

Im trying a basic query to learn about timestamps in db queries. I have a db with a field 'time' which is a timestamp. I have a basic query to return records where "time" is greater than a keyed value ($t1). I have checked that mytime() is formatted correctly (commented off to illustrate). I have a single record set to todays date. I'm expecting it to return or not as I change the value of $t1 ... but it's not. where am I going wrong?

> ```
>   date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
> ```

```
    $year = '2011';
    $month = '10';
    $day = '11';
    $t1 = mktime(0,0,0, $month, $day, $year);
    //echo date("d/m/y : H:i:s", $t1); // this works fine!


    mysql_select_db(DATABASE_NAME, $connection);
    $client = "demo/";

    $result = mysql_query
    (
        "SELECT *
        FROM " .SESSIONDB. " 
        WHERE client = '$client' 
        AND page = 'interaction.php'
        AND time > '$t1'
        "
    );
```

Comment: You should be using MySQL's DATETIME instead of INT to store times.

Comment: But I will want the ability in the future to handle timezones,  so I need timestamp right?

Comment: You're right. However, MySQL also has a TIMESTAMP format as well (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html)

Answer (score 0):

You set the record to

```
mktime(0,0,0, $month, $day, $year);
```

and you set your variable to

```
$t1 = mktime(0,0,0, $month, $day, $year);
```

But you compare the two using > (more than)... 2 is not > 2, it is == or >=

:)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what tour saying

Comment: You said "I have a single record set to todays date." and you use MKTIME to generate today's time but you compare both with "greater than" (>) instead of "greater than or equal to" (>=)

Comment: I get your point (sorry for being unclear), But i'm expecting the argument to return true if I move MKTIME to yesterday's date, but it's not.

Comment: I don't understand how it cannot work in this case... sorry. maybe you should change to dates all in GMT/0 and handle your timezoning based on the user's settings. I sincerely never use timestamps because they make the database hard to read if you need to debug something.

Comment: Mathieu, my thanks for your comments. Hit a train of thought. Random search. The fix was to cast FROM_UNIXTIME($t1) inside the query. Perfect!. Thanks for spending the time.